# Rails ActiveRecord - Comparing Associated Data in Different Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'd love a "code" answer, but even telling me the theory/what terms I should search for to find how how to do the below would be helpful.

I have Workers and I have Jobs. The Workers have Skills through WorkerSkills and the Jobs have Skills through JobSkills.

I want to return a result of Jobs for a given Worker where the Worker's Skills in WorkerSkills include all the JobSkills for a Job.

So if a Job needs Skills: Typing, Editing, Posting, Reviewing and a Worker only has skills Typing and Reviewing, the result won't include that job, but if a Job needs Skills: Typing and Editing, but a Worker has Skills Typing, Editing, Posting, Reviewing then that Job will be included in the result.

I already have a method "available_for_bid" in the Job model which I think would work with some modified code. Thanks!

```
class Worker < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :skills, through: :worker_skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_skills
  has_many :jobs, through: :job_skills
  has_many :worker_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :worker_skills
end

class WorkerSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :worker
  belongs_to :skill
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills
  has_many :job_skills
  has_many :skills, through: :job_skills

  def self.available_for_bid(worker)
      where.not(id: worker.job_ids).where('start_date > ?', Date.today)
  end
end

class JobSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :job
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

Comment: Typing, Editing, Posting, Reviewing are 4 different record in skill model ?

Comment: @Vishal Exactly, so I will have (via an admin panel) added in data for the Skills, the Skills table will be simple, just a skill_id and a description; so what (I guess) I really want is to be able to compare the "skill_ids" in the WorkerSkills table with the "skills_id" in the JobSkills table

Answer (score 0):

To get an array with appropriate jobs for a worker, you need to have something like this:

```
def available_jobs_for(worker)
  Job.all.map do |job|
    valid_job = job.skill_ids.map {|js_id| js_id.in?(worker.abilities.flat_map{|wa| wa.skill_id }) }.all?
    return job if valid_job
    nil
  end.compact
end
```

and I suggest you to move this code out of the model. Use query/service object. This is a very fast solution and can be optimized.

Also you can add has_many :skills association to worker model.